# Regular Expression for password

Tags: c#, regex

I'm not really good at regular expressions. I need to do the following to validate if a password, entered by the user, is correct or not.

Criteria:

1. Must contain at least one number
2. Must contain at least one letter from A-Z or a-z (case does not matter as long as they enter is a letter).
3. The password must be a minimum of 8 characters

Comment: Knowning the type of regexp (POSIX, PCRE) or at least your platform/tool/programming language might help people willing to reply.

Comment: I'm sorry, I did not know there was a difference. I'm doing the validation for the password in C#. Bennor's reply helped, thanks for replying back.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Za-z]).{8,}
```

The first part (`(?=.*\d)`) searches for at least one number, the second part (`(?=.*[A-Za-z])`) searches for at least one letter, and the last part (`.{8,}`) ensures it's at least 8 characters long.

You might want to put an upper limit on the length of the password like this:

```
^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Za-z]).{8,30}$
```

The 30 in that spot limits it to 30 characters in length, and the ^ and $ anchor it to the start and end of the string.

Comment: Wow hat was quick.  I just tested it.  It works great.  Thanks Bennor. Also thanks for the explanation.