# Regular expression help

Tags: asp.net, regex, visual-studio-2010

I need a regular expression that requires a password to have at least 8 characters and a number.

Also, is there a website that allows me to generate regular expressions automatically?

Comment: There are so many questions covering this topic, see for example [questions/3489693/regular-expression-for-password](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3489693/regular-expression-for-password)

Comment: Thanks stema..your answer provided me with a solution

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you use 2 regex validations:

```
\d
```

and

```
.{8,}
```

much more understandable.

Comment: this is a nice solution. it just states that you want at least 8 characters. and the "\d" just says i want one or more numbers.

Answer (score 1):

This checks for a digit in password string

```
^(?=.*\d+)[\w]{8,}$
```

Answer (score 1):

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
namespace TestConsoleAppCSharp
{



      class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                string[] passwords = {"test123", "testtest", "testtest123"};
                foreach (string pw in passwords)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(Regex.IsMatch(pw, @"^.*(?=.{8,})(?=.*\d)") ? String.Format("{0}: Yepp", pw) : String.Format("{0}: Nope", pw));
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If characters in "8 characters and a number" means "non-digit characters" then I wouldn't use a regex to validate this. Is too complicated to do it with one regex.

Is easier just to check each character and increment two variables (one of non digit chars'c' and one for digits 'd') and check the values in the end:

d >=1 && c >=1 && d+c >= 8 <- good password

Later edit: I just saw the solution with regex lookahead. While that one works I still believe that this problem can be solved with only one traversal, with no lookahead